# Alternative for is_taxonomy() to workaround theme's default sidebar

Tags: custom-taxonomy, widgets, taxonomy, sidebar, reset

My Wordpress theme is using some code in the "sidebar.php" file that tells it that some pages should always use the default sidebar. This was fine until I found that each and every custom taxonomy (example: "taxonomy-mountains.php") page is defaulting to this default sidebar.

I thought about catching this with `is_taxonomy()`, but that's deprecated and won't work. Any better programmers out there with an idea of how I could fix this now. Something like `if(is_taxonomy('mountains')){}` would've worked fine. Below code is an excerpt, if you think something is missing let me know.

```
//Default sidebar
$selected_sidebar_replacement = 'Sidebar Widgets';

//If is page or single
if(is_singular()){
global $wp_query;
$post = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
$selected_sidebar_replacement = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sbg_selected_sidebar_replacement', true);

//If default selected
if($selected_sidebar_replacement == '0' || $selected_sidebar_replacement == ''){
$selected_sidebar_replacement = 'Sidebar Widgets';
                    }

// Reset the global $the_post
wp_reset_query();

                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function that replaces `is_taxonomy()` is named `taxonomy_exists()`. Than there's also `is_tax()` and `is_tag()` that check if the query is for a taxonomy archive page.

**EDIT**

`$selected_sidebar_replacement == '0' || $selected_sidebar_replacement == ''` won't work. You're not checking the type.

Better do it like this:

```
if ( ! $selected_sidebar_replacement OR emtpy( $selected_sidebar_replacement ) )
```

Comment: Thanks @kaiser, however I don't know how to use this to display for example the sidebar "gear" when I'm in the taxonomy "product-brand". Below doesn't work.
`if(is_tax( 'product-brand' )){
        $selected_sidebar_replacement = 'Gear';
       }`

Comment: See Edit (filler)

Comment: You're talking in riddles... "you can't change the taxonomy on your custom taxonomy pages"? Change? How? What? btw: ↑ you've been checking against `'0'` which is a string. That shouldn't happen when selecting a string...

Comment: TYPO:"The issue I'm having is that I can't change the SIDEBAR on my custom taxonomy pages." Yes I have been checking against '0', and while it isn't a string, it is working, and your suggestion isn't. I'll look in to that later, but first I really need to figure out how to display different sidebars when I'm on different custom taxonomies.

Comment: @WouterB As you marked it as solution: What exactly _was_ the solution?